# How to add my products to the right side of my Image?

Tags: image, flutter, web, product

I'm building an flutter web app my image is on the left side of the page not full screen and now I want to
display my products next to my image but I don't to get I to work .I tryed to wrap it with and column but no luck I tryed to wrap it with a row allso no luck[look at image move products from left to open space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx2z0.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:web_windmillsa_tech/tools/store.dart';
import 'favorites.dart';
import 'messages.dart';
import 'cart.dart';
import 'notifications.dart';
import 'history.dart';[![enter image description here][1]][1]
import 'profile.dart';
import 'delivery.dart';
import 'aboutUs.dart';
import 'loginlogout.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  BuildContext context;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Welcome to WindMill South-Africa Online Tech Store',
            style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 25.0)),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(
                Icons.favorite,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                 Navigator.of(context).push(new CupertinoPageRoute(
                     builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                         new WindMillFavorities()));
              }),
          new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new IconButton(
                  icon: new Icon(
                    Icons.chat,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                     Navigator.of(context).push(new CupertinoPageRoute(
                         builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                             new WindMillMassages()));
                  }),
              new CircleAvatar(
                radius: 10.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                child: new Text(
                  '0',
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12.0),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: new Container(
        // child: new Container(
        //   width: 500,
        //   height: 1000,
        //   decoration: BoxDecoration(
        //     image: DecorationImage(
        //       image: AssetImage('assets/images/windmill.jpg'),
        //       fit: BoxFit.fill,
        //     ),
        //   ),
        //   child: new Row(
        //     children: <Widget>[
        //       new Container(
        //         child: new Flexible(
        //             child: new GridView.builder(
        //           gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        //               crossAxisCount: 3),
        //           itemCount: 4,
        //           itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        //             return new Card(
        //               child: new Stack(
        //                 alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
        //                 children: <Widget>[
        //                   new Row(
        //                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        //                     children: <Widget>[
        //                       new Text('itemName'),
        //                       new Text('itemPrice'),
        //                     ],
        //                   ),
        //                 ],
        //               ),
        //             );
        //           },
        //         )),
        //       ),
        //     ],
        //   ),
        // ),

        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 500,
              height: 1000,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                // image: DecorationImage(
                //   image: AssetImage('assets/images/windmill.jpg'),
                //   fit: BoxFit.fill,
                // ),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1266627.jpg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: new Flexible(
                  child: new GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3),
                itemCount: 4,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return new Card(
                    child: new Stack(
                      alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Text('itemName'),
                            new Text('itemPrice'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              )),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        children: <Widget>[
          new FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(new CupertinoPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => new WindMillCart()));
              },
              child: new Icon(Icons.shopping_cart)),
          new CircleAvatar(
            radius: 10.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            child: new Text(
              '0',
              style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12.0),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: new Text('Corneluis J Heunis'),
              accountEmail: new Text('corneluis@windmillsa.com'),
              currentAccountPicture: new CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: new Icon(Icons.person),
              ),
            ),
            new ListTile(
              leading: new CircleAvatar(
                child: new Icon(
                  Icons.notifications,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              title: new Text('Order Notifications'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(new CupertinoPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                        new WindMillNotifications()));
              },
            ),
            new ListTile(
              leading: new CircleAvatar(
                child: new Icon(
                  Icons.history,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              title: new Text('Order History'),
              onTap: () {
                // Navigator.of(context).push(new CupertinoPageRoute(
                //     builder: (BuildContext context) => new WindMillHistory()));
              },
            ),
            new Divider(),
            new ListTile(
              leading: new CircleAvatar(
                child: new Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              title: new Text('Profile Settings'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(new CupertinoPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => new WindMillProfile()));
              },
            ),
            new ListTile(
              leading: new CircleAvatar(
                child: new Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              title: new Text('Delivery Address'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(new CupertinoPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => new WindMillDelivery()));
              },
            ),
            new Divider(),
            new ListTile(
              trailing: new CircleAvatar(
                child: new Icon(
                  Icons.help,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              title: new Text('About Us'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(new CupertinoPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => new WindMillAbout()));
              },
            ),
            new ListTile(
              trailing: new CircleAvatar(
                child: new Icon(
                  Icons.exit_to_app,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              title: new Text('Login'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(new CupertinoPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => new WindMillLogin()));
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[here is the output what i understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52yoi.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure if u understood the question I don't want image to the right only products to the right??

Comment: look at line 80 of my code from there on down I have a problem new Flexible has a gridview builder so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong there please help

Comment: what you want on left side

Comment: Hi there Akshay take a look at the picture I posted with the question . So what I want is the image on the left hand side and the products on the right hand side If u look at the picture it show that the products are cramped inside the image I want to display the prduct on the right hand side

Comment: Hi there look at the link where the question is I added an picture of what i want all I want is to have the windmill image on the left hand side and the products on the right hand side next to the image hope u understand what I mean????

Comment: i edit your code what i understand your image in leftside and products in right side. i give comment on code for image and use network image you can use your image. adjust image height width as you need

Comment: Hi there AKSHAY thanks for your help that's just what I needed